# Understanding the difference between `self`and `cls` and whether they refer to the same attributes

Tags: python, class, self

I'm trying to understand if there are differences between `self` and `cls` but I'm struggling, even though a lot of discussion on this topic exists. For instance:

```
class maclass():
    A = "class method"

    def __init__(self):
        self.B = "instance method"

    def getA_s(self):
        print(self.A)

    def getA_c(cls):
        print(cls.A)

    def getB_s(self):
        print(self.B)

    def getB_c(cls):
        print(cls.B)

C = maclass()
C.getA_s()
C.getA_c()
C.getB_s()
C.getB_c()
```

which give me:

```
class method
class method
instance method
instance method
```

So whether I use `self` or `cls`, it always refers to the same variable. When I add a `self.A` in the `Init__`, the cls.A is just replaced

```
def __init__(self):
        self.B = "instance method"
        self.A = "new instance method"
```

and I get:

```
new instance method
new instance method
instance method
instance method
```

I don't understand the point of having two ways to call a class member if they are the same? I know this is a common question on this forum, yet I really don't understand why we would use different words to refer to the same thing (we even could use any variable name instead of `self` or `cls`).

### update

In the following case:

```
class maclass():
    A = "class method, "

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = "instance method, "

    def getA_s(self):
        print(self.A) #give me "instance method, "

    @classmethod
    def getA_c(cls):
        print(cls.A) #give me "class method, "

C = maclass()
C.getA_s()
C.getA_c()
print(' ')
print(C.A) #give me "instance method, "
```

I get :

```
instance method, 
class method, 

instance method,
```

So in this case, in `maclass`: `cls.A` and `self.A` do not refer to the same variable.

Comment: They are just naming conventions. You can name that first argument anything you like.

Comment: Try calling it `kevin`, it will still work in the same way.  We use `self` and `cis` as a convention for *readability*, nothing more.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*All* your methods are instance methods. None of them are class methods.

The first argument to a method is named `self` only by convention. You can name it anything you want, and naming it `cls` instead will not make it a reference to the class. That the first argument is bound to an instance is due to how method lookup works (accessing `C.getA_s` produces a *bound method object*, and calling that object causes `C` to be passed into the original function `getA_s`), the names of the parameters play no role.

In your methods, you are merely referencing instance attributes. That the `A` attribute is ultimately only defined on the class doesn't matter, you are still accessing that attribute through `C.A` (where `C` is the instance you created), not `maclass.A`. Looking up an attribute on the instance will also find attributes defined on the class if there is no instance attribute shadowing it.

To make a method a class method, decorate it with the [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
@classmethod
def getA_c(cls):
    print(cls.A)
```

Now `cls` will always be a reference to the class, never to the instance. I need to stress again that it doesn't actually matter to Python what name I picked for that first argument, but `cls` is the convention here as that makes it easier to remind the reader that this method is bound to the class object.

Note that if you do this for the `getB_c()` method, then trying to access `cls.B` in the method will fail because there is no `B` attribute on the `maclass` class object.

That's because `classmethod` wraps the function in a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that overrides the normal function binding behaviour. It is the descriptor *protocol* that causes methods to be bound to instances when accessed as attributes on the instance, a `classmethod` object redirects that binding process.

Here is a short demonstration with inline comments, I used the Python convertions for naming classes (using CamelCase), and for instances, attributes, functions and methods (using snake_case):

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     class_attribute = "String attribute on the class"
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.instance_attribute = "String attribute on the instance"
...     @classmethod
...     def get_class_attribute(cls):
...         return cls.class_attribute
...     def get_instance_attribute(self):
...         return self.instance_attribute
...     @classmethod
...     def get_instance_attribute_on_class(cls):
...         return cls.instance_attribute
...
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.class_attribute  # class attributes are visible on the instance
'String attribute on the class'
>>> MyClass.class_attribute   # class attributes are also visible on the class
'String attribute on the class'
>>> instance.get_class_attribute()  # bound to the class, but that doesn't matter here
'String attribute on the class'
>>> instance.class_attribute = "String attribute value overriding the class attribute"
>>> instance.get_class_attribute()  # bound to the class, so the class attribute is found
'String attribute on the class'
>>> MyClass.get_instance_attribute_on_class()   # fails, there is instance_attribute on the class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in get_instance_attribute_on_class
AttributeError: type object 'MyClass' has no attribute 'instance_attribute'
```

Note that the class method accesses the class attribute even though we set an attribute with the same name on the instance.

Next is binding behaviour:

```
>>> MyClass.get_instance_attribute   # accessing the method on the class gives you the function
<function MyClass.get_instance_attribute at 0x10f94f268>
>>> instance.get_instance_attribute  # accessing the method on the instance gives you the bound method
<bound method MyClass.get_instance_attribute of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x10f92b5f8>>
>>> MyClass.get_class_attribute      # class methods are always bound, to the class
<bound method MyClass.get_class_attribute of <class '__main__.MyClass'>>
>>> instance.get_class_attribute     # class methods are always bound, to the class
<bound method MyClass.get_class_attribute of <class '__main__.MyClass'>>
```

The bound methods tell you what they are bound *to*, calling the method passes in that bound object as the first argument. That object can also be introspected by looking at the `__self__` attribute of a bound method:

```
>>> instance.get_instance_attribute.__self__  # the instance
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10f92b5f8>
>>> instance.get_class_attribute.__self__     # the class
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

Comment: So in your example, `cls.A` differ from `self.A`. If I do a `C.A` from a `maclass` instance I will get the `self.A` from `maclass`, Am I right?

Comment: @ymmx: I'm not sure what you are asking. What are `cls` and `self` there? The parameter names in your example code? Those are always the same object, the instance of the `maclass` you assigned to `C`.

Comment: @ymmx: If you add `@classmethod` to your `get*_c` definitions, then `cls` will be bound to the `maclass` class, and so `cls.A` will only ever find the class attribute. Calling `C.getB_c()` would fail, because there is no `B` attribute on the `maclass` class object.

Comment: Ok I get it. So `self`and `cls` are different if at least a classmethod decorator is used.

Comment: I found this answer to be exceptionally thorough and clear. Thank you!