# can't assign a value to a variable in a @classmethod

Tags: python, class, class-method

I have a bit of background in Java and used `static` variables and methods a lot. I am new to python and learning about using `@classmethod` as a static method.

Here is code,

```
import redis

class GetClients:
    r = None

    @classmethod
    def connect_r(cls, host, port, db):
        r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=db)

    @classmethod
    def get_clients(cls, clients_key):
        return r.smembers(clients_key)
```

My code first create a variable `r` and then inside a `classmethod` it assigns it to a redis connection, `r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=db)`

In the next method `get_clients`, I am using the value of `r` to invoke a function on it., but I keep getting the following error

> NameError: name 'r' is not defined

here is how i am using the class,

```
clients = GetClients()
clients.connect_r("localhost", 6379, 0)
allc = clients.get_clients("clients")
```

can someone please explain why I cannot access `r` in the 2nd method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `r` in both class methods, you should replace `r` with `cls.r`.
like this:

```
import redis

class GetClients:
    r = None

    @classmethod
    def connect_r(cls, host, port, db):
        cls.r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=db)

    @classmethod
    def get_clients(cls, clients_key):
        return cls.r.smembers(clients_key)
```

But I think that your way of implementing these methods are a little bit wrong, you should not use class methods for this demands.

> can someone please explain why I cannot access` in the 2nd method?

I should say that you can not even access r in `connect_r` too. that `r` is another variable with a different scop and if you want to see what will happen just change `r` to `cls.r` in `get_clients`, you will see that this method will returns `None` and it seems that `connect_r` method is not setting the actual `r`, for accessing those variables in class methods you should use `cls`.
also see the difference between `cls` and `self` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880314/understanding-the-difference-between-selfand-cls-as-they-refer-to-the-same-a).